# CSS - Why is my navigation still full width on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Morning All,

I'm hoping someone can advise me on the amendments I need to make to my website's CSS to make it display correctly on a mobile device.

At the moment when you view the website in mobile device the menu navigation is displaying at the same size as if it was on a desktop PC, but the rest of the website looks absolutely fine.

From which I can see the navigation uses % once it hits a specific width.

So how can I correct this issue?

I look forward to hearing your fixes.

Please see the website below:

http://www.blanchel.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

if you don't want to allow zooming, add max-scale at the end:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: this has solved the issue on my Android browser, however it still does the same on the Iphones browser... any ideas?

Comment: hmm try adding to content > initial-scale=1.0